# Don't have permissions to save file in Mac OS X using Vim, even after using sudo

Tags: macos, mac, permissions, file-permissions, sudo

I’m trying to edit the following file on my machine:

```
/etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

First I got an error stating that I don’t have permissions to change the file, fair enough. I then used `sudo` but I still get the same error. Any idea why this would happen?

Comment: Check with ls your permissions. If you have no permissions you can change it by typing: chmod 700 httpd.conf. As a result you should get full permission for the user.

Comment: @Valinho 700 is quite restrictive for others, not really needed. And no need for it to be executable either.

Comment: @slhck you are right, but the question if the problem can be resolved by changing permissions?

Comment: Yes, if your file permissions don’t allow you or your group to edit that file that can be the reason but there is no way to know if that is the reason that you can no write on it. I have no problem with: sudo nano /etc/apache2/httpd.conf Do you have your Apache service off? Did you create the super user?

Answer (score 0):

You say you used `sudo` but what editor did you use? In your example you just say you attempted to edit:

```
/etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

But if you just entered that path in the command line you would get this error:

> -bash: /etc/apache2/httpd.conf: Permission denied

That is because if you just type in `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` and then hit <kbd>return</kbd> it would attempt to actually run the file… And that file is not a binary or even a script with execution rights.

And even if you added `sudo` before that path like this:

```
sudo /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

Then—after being prompted for your password—you would still get an error like this:

> sudo: /etc/apache2/httpd.conf: command not found

If you need to edit with `sudo` you need to specify the editor you want to use—such as `nano`—like this:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

And *then* you can edit the file `httpd.conf` via `nano` which was launched with `sudo` rights.

FWIW, the checking the file on my Mac OS X 19.5 (Mavericks) install shows the following permissions; which are standard, normal and `sudo` user editable:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  18121 Jan 25 01:44 /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```